# How do I pass user name and password in an http post request from angular 4

Tags: angular, api, http

I need to send username and password to a login api using angular http post request. Here is my code:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('username', username);
    params.set('password', password);
    this.headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'authorization': 'Basic' });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers, method: RequestMethod.Post, params: params });
    return this.http.post(this.config.baseUrlAuthSvc + this.config.login, this.options)
        .map((response) => { return response; })
```

I am getting the following error in response:

> Request URL:http://111.22.333.44:55/api/token
>   Request Method:OPTIONS
>   Status Code:400 Bad Request
>   Remote Address:172.31.131.13:85
>   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Am I missing something?

Comment: You might need to set the request body to `username=enteredUsername&password=enteredPassword`

Comment: @jason yes, that's what I did. params should be used in get request

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this way

```
return $http.post(URL, data, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        return response;
    });
```

data is the input param e.g. as below

```
var data = "username=" + username + "password=" + password;
```

Comment: I missed the angular 4, this answer will be helpful in case of 1.x versions

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, in a post request it's not possible to pass params in requestoptions. The second parameter in http.post request is body, so I passed the string 'username=xyz&password=123' as second paramter and it worked fine.

Key point is, if it's a http post request refrain from using params.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use HttpParams to pass password instead of querystring concatenation of username + password.

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    Authorization: `BASIC ${clientId}`,            
});

const tokenPath = 'https://your-api-endpoint/token';

// form data
const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('grant_type', 'password')
    .set('username', username)
    .set('password', password);

return this.http.post<any>(tokenPath, params, { headers: httpHeaders }).pipe(
    map((token) => {
        this.setSession(token);
        return token;
    },
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('login'))
));
```